# after updates i got a debian bootlogo?

Tags: grub2, debian

last night i had some update I think that that was the cause i didn't check 
what updates and now when I boot I got a **[DEBIAN](http://www.debian.org/) BOOTLOGO**???
and i have a [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/) 11.10 amd64? i also installed gnome-shell.
everything works fine but still its strange
my question is what is the cause, and is it a bug (do I need to file a bug report)
and how to fixit

Comment: How did you install `gnome-shell`?

Comment: via ubuntu-software-center i deleted gnome-shell with software-center but my boot-logo is still a debian boot-logo???

Comment: I think that the problem might be the package `desktop-base`, which installs some plymouth themes and other things. Anyway, you don't need to use gnome-shell, as it is a dependency only of the package `gnome`.

Comment: thanks i removed the desktop-base rebooted and now i got back my ubuntu boot-logo :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I put this in an answer, so you can accept it.

The problem it with the package `desktop-base`, which installs some plymouth themes and other things.

You don't need it to use `gnome-shell`, as it is a dependency only of the package `gnome`, so you can remove it safely and the logo will be back as usual.